# I am trying to automate transfer of an incoming messages in my mailbox into csv files

Tags: python

It prints out a list :

```
['10:30 ET STC 1 @NQH1 [121] \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n-- \r\nThis mail was checked by AVG.\r\nhttp://www.avg.cz\r\n']
```

I wold need the list to contain only the actual message and get a rid of the redundant stuff, should look like this:

```
['10:30','ET','STC','1','@NQH1', [121]]
```

so that it can then be converted to csv.

I am struggling with it for a week, trying `print(my_inbox.split(","))` etc., but it doesn't work with lists and is not bringing me anywhrere..

Comment: seems simple enough, split your string by spaces and take everything before all those newlines `\r\n\r\n...`. the reeason split with `,` commas didnt work is because you dont have any commas in the string. also, your list contains a single item so try `my_inbox[0].split(" ")`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```py
# list of strings
content = ['10:30 ET STC 1 @NQH1 [121] \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n-- \r\nThis mail was checked by AVG.\r\nhttp://www.avg.cz\r\n']

# print for demonstration - store on list/directly write to csv
for mail in content:
    print(mail.split()) # ['10:30', 'ET', 'STC', '1', '@NQH1', '[121]', '--', 'This', 'mail', 'was', 'checked', 'by', 'AVG.', 'http://www.avg.cz']
    # just keep first 6 entries
    print(mail.split()[:6]) # ['10:30', 'ET', 'STC', '1', '@NQH1', '[121]']
```

Comment: Stefan, thanks a lot. I was struggling so long with it . The split already functions me but the part   print(mail.split([:6])) is still giving me an "invalit syntax" error  But I am very grateful I move forward... :-)

Comment: Briliant!  Thank you again.